# when will the incareful features harm the model?

Tags: machine-learning, feature-selection, feature-engineering

I am working on financial prediction problem(time-series prediction problem).

I think feature engineering is importance in this problem. So i am careful to check the feature's effectiveness. And i perfer linear regression, because i think it's easy to explain, and I am not good  at machine learning models

But i think i have another method: build a lot of features without careful check, select good model to handle it.

So, my question is:

In which model, add what kind of features, will harm this model's ability?

And Is there any models, i can just add without worrying the harm of trash features? in this model, what should i pay attention to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In very simple words,

Those models which use all the features of the instances will suffer from irrelevant features *e.g. Neural Nets, KNN etc*.

While the models which have an internal strategy to compares the features to decide the best while training will not suffer(*at least for this reason) e.g. Tree*

Here is a snap from "*The Elements of Statistical Learning, by Trevor Hastie,
Robert Tibshirani, Jerome Friedman*

[image]

You can also read this section [10.3 Effect of Irrelevant Features](http://www.feat.engineering/feature-selection-simulation.html) from "*Feature Engineering and Selection: A Practical Approach for Predictive Models by Max Kuhn and Kjell Johnson*"

You can try these approaches to filters the features -

- Using correlation with the target
- Using Feature Importance
- Using L1 penalty

Also, keep in mind that you might face other issues because of this and the models may suffer indirectly e.g.

- High dimensionality
- Issue of Trees "*default feature importance approach"* with high Cardinal features etc.

Comment: great, thanks. very professional